# A linguagem do back-end muda a forma de um aplicativo ser desenvolvido?

Tags: delphi-7, back-end, app-hibrido

Tenho um projeto em que preciso realizar a construção de um aplicativo híbrido usando um back-end em Delphi. Mas antes de embarcar no projeto preciso tirar algumas dúvidas, pois nunca trabalhei com Delphi.

Normalmente em um aplicativo híbrido fazemos a comunicação com o back-end via Ajax, onde enviamos parâmetros get ou post para uma URL do back-end e pegamos o retorno que geralmente é um JSON. Esse é o comportamento padrão quando falamos em um back-end em PHP ou Java.

Mas e em Delphi? A forma de desenvolver o aplicativo é alterada? Ou não muda nada? Fazemos normalmente requisições por Ajax enviando dados get ou post e coletando resultados em JSON?

Sei que isso depende do sistema em Delphi, mas independente disso, um back-end em Delphi poderia funcionar como um em PHP ou Java, comentando requisições Ajax com post e get e retornar um JSON?

Comment: Se o servidor conseguir responder a POST e GET retornar JSON não importa a linguagem, pode ser ASP, Java, PHP, NodeJS, tanto faz, poderia retornar ate um XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que não deva mudar, não. Poderia construir seu back-end usando rest, dessa forma não importa qual linguagem você usaria no front-end, todas iriam consumir seu back-end usando requisições ajax, trocando JSON. Estou construindo uma pequena aplicação, no back-end uso C#/MVC/EF, no front-end uso Angular. O Angular é otimo.

Answer (score 0):

Uma  dica para você, tente usar linguagens que dê para trabalhar com orientação a objetos. Trabalhar com Delphi vai te dar dor de cabeça na hora de dar manutenção. Em relação a ajax com post e get retornando um json. Muitas linguagens tem o poder de fazer isso, eu mesmo faço isso no trabalho com PHP.